# How can I produce and consume messages in same endpoint using kafka reactor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to create a reactive endpoint using WebFlux and Reactor Kafka in order to get the notifications for a user.

The idea is to bring the stored notifications in the database in the first place and then keep the endpoint open to listen to new notifications.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/notifications/users/{userId}")
Flux<ServerSentEvent> getEventsFlux(@PathVariable String userId) {
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> kafkaFlux = kafkaReceiver.receive();
    kafkaNotificationService.generateFirstNotification(userId);
    return kafkaFlux.filter(sN -> sN.value().toLowerCase().contains(userId))
            .map(r -> ServerSentEvent.builder().event(r.value()).build());
}
```

Service

```
public void generateFirstNotification(String userId) {
    Flux<Notification> notifications = notificationRepository.findAllByUserId(UUID.fromString(userId));
    sender.<Notification>send(notifications
                .map(i -> SenderRecord.create(new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, "Key", objectMapper.convertValue(i, JSONObject.class).toJSONString()), i)))
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Send failed", e))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

If I create two endpoints like the ones below, one for receiving messages and other for producing the first notifications(using the service above) it's working.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/notifications/produce-messages/{userId}")
void getEventsFlux(@PathVariable String userId) {
    kafkaService.generateFirstNotification(userId);
}

@GetMapping("/notifications/get-messages/{userId}")
Flux<ServerSentEvent> getMessages(@PathVariable String userId) {
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> kafkaFlux = kafkaReceiver.receive();
    return kafkaFlux.filter(sN ->sN.value().toLowerCase().contains(userId))
                .map(r -> ServerSentEvent.builder().event(r.value()).build());
}
```

I would like to have one single endpoint to do everything.

Thank you so much
Best regards

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_reactive_kafka_binder

Comment: Not clear what you are a asking. So, you want `findAllByUserId()` to be as a part of that `getEventsFlux`? Why then do you need Kafka in between?

Comment: Hi Artem! I don't want that specifically, right now I have one endpoint to get the messages from the topic, and another one to produce them. Instead, I want both thing in the same endpoint.

Comment: But you already call that `generateFirstNotification()`  from your `getEventsFlux()` controller method. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Ideally, Kafka consumer is always running on a background thread. Not started from HTTP action. Then your HTTP action can query the database that is populated from that Kafka consumer, running elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Artem! The problem is that with that code I don't receive any messages. With two different endpoints everything is working fine, I get all the notifications from the database, but if I use only one, I don't get any notification

Comment: Hi OneC! I have to run the reactive consumer from the front-end in order to get all the notifications in a reactive way, I mean, if I have a new notification, I want it on my app asap, so because of that we have to open the consumer from http request

Comment: maybe you could return Flux from generateFirstNotification method and then just subsribe a new Consumer to it which will call "kafkaFlux.filter(..."

Comment: Let's see if `auto.offset.reset=earliest` cam help you somehow!

Comment: It didn't work :(